# Why is the Careers PDF export in Verdana when the preview is in Helvetica?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, export

The entire site is set in Helvetica, with the occasional exception of a header in Trebuchet that sticks out like a sore thumb and a bit of Georgia for the background.

There's a PDF export of my CV, which first shows me a preview using many of the same typefaces; when I click the "Export to PDF" button, I get a PDF that is full of Verdana. What happened? That's not a very good preview.

Answer (score 5):

The font was changed to Arial and is now correctly matches the preview in exported pdfs.